# Initial MDT setup and cant get computer to join domain sucessfully

Tags: mdt

Hope I can provide some context here as I've been tasked with standing up MDT at my company but I've never even heard of it before and am still entry level in the IT field. I was able to setup MDT but when i push an image to a computer i get prompted to put in credentials and they wont take no matter what creds i put. I already checked the bootstrap and customsetup files with the recommendations from other articles and still same thing. Not sure if its something i messed up on in initial configuration of MDT? not sure where else to start or even look. any and all recommendations is highly appreciated!

Comment: Usually in your image it woud be an local account as the image is not yet in the domain.

Comment: if you’re having trouble joining the domain, you’ll be looking for ZTIDomainJoin.log. It’ll be in the %WINDIR%\TEMP\DeploymentLogs. For most of you, that’ll be C:\Windows\Temp\DeploymentLogs or your server side logs location if you have that configured as well, just use Trace32 to read them, because they’re pretty hard to decipher from notepad.